# has/have got OR has/have been

Tags: verbs, tenses

"The match has got delayed" - Can we use "got" rather than "been" in this sentence?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not in that context, because when *got* is followed by a past participle it often has the meaning ‘become’. A delay isn’t generally something that ‘becomes’. You can, however, use the construction in a sentence such as ‘My hand has got stuck’.

Comment: Can you please provide an example where got is followed by a past participle?

Comment: I just did: ‘My hand has got stuck’.

Comment: Passive participle has _to be_ or _to get_ as the helping verb. E.g., _We got screwed_.
Present participle can have _get_ too (though is not limited to _get_ and _be_): _Let's get going!_

Comment: Isn't gotten the same construct as been

Comment: In the US, _The match has gotten delayed_ would be appropriate, as an example of the _Get_-Passive, if there were some outside force (hurricane, bureaucracy, traffic, pirate attack, drunk fans) causing the delay. But _The match has been delayed_ is acceptable in all cases.